# opengl GLFW application bad performance in debug mode

Tags: opengl, glfw

I'm making a small demo application learning opengl 3.3 using GLFW. MY problem is that, if I run a release compile it runs at about 120 fps. A debug compile runs at about 15 fps. Why would that be?

It's a demo shooting lots of particles that move and rotate.

Answer (score 3):

If the app isn't optimized and spends a long time executing non-OpenGL commands, the OpenGL device can be easily in a idle situation.

You should profile the app without OpenGl commands (as if you have an infinitely fast OpenGL device) and check your FPS. If it's very slow this will be an indication that your app is CPU bound (probably in release mode too).

In addition if you're setting debug options in opengl/glsl, poor performance wouldn't be a big surprise.

Debug mode should be used to debug the app and 15fps still gives you a more or less interactive experience.

If the particle system is animated with the CPU (OpenGl only renders), you should consider a GPU accelerated solution.

Comment: I just tested without GL commands. FPS WITH GL: 19 debug, 115 release. FPS WITHOUT GL: 25 debug, 530 release. About the rest of your post, the movement and rotation iterations all happen on the CPU per-particle in every frame. To accelerate this the only way I know is pass a huge buffer/uniform to my shader with all the info that I now store in a Class::Particle and move the computations there. Would that be efficient considering the memory transfer needed in every frame?

Comment: Transferring a large table of particles to gpu every frame doesn't look like a good solution. Try to figure out a way where you don't transfer data from/to gpu every frame. Make sure the particle system is an actual bottleneck before doing major changes